# NSMutable Array and leaking Problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Hey - does somebody know why i get a leak when i use this line of code ??? :

```
[self setModules:[[aDictionary objectForKey:KEY_MODULES] mutableCopy]];
```

Thanks in advance
pk

Comment: So long as the modules property is declared as retain, your leak is not on that line of code. (Leaks initially shows where the memory was allocated, you have to poke around to find the actual leak.) More likely, you're not releasing modules in your dealloc.

Comment: @Robot K: Actually, the leak *is* in that line of code.  -mutableCopy gives you a reference that you do own.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about it backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you create a copy of existing object via `mutableCopy` then you're responsible to release it (assuming you also retain it in setModules method):

```
[self setModules:[[[aDictionary objectForKey:KEY_MODULES] mutableCopy] autorelease]];
```

Check also that you release `modules` iVar in your class's dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

`mutableCopy` creates a new copy with a retainCount of 1 and needs to be released.

```
[self setModules:[[[aDictionary objectForKey:KEY_MODULES] mutableCopy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Actually, it creates a copy with a retain count of *at least* 1.